# Draw a pie grath with achartEngine from values in Preference xml

Tags: android, xml, preferences, achartengine

I am trying to draw a pie from values stored in an XML preference file. I have 2 values, x y  and need to draw a pie from this values. It does not pass the variables through the class. If I put integers instead of x and y, the graph is working perfectly, but I cannot pass the x and y as variables.
How can get this working?

```
public class MGraphPie extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String x = preferences.getString("amountx", "DEFAULT");
    String y = preferences.getString("amounty", "DEFAULT");
}



public Intent getIntent (Context context) {

    int[] values = {x, y};
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Pe");
    int k = 0;
    for (int value: values) {
        series.add("Section " + ++k, value);

    }
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.CYAN, Color.RED };

    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color : colors) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, series, renderer, "PLEAaa");
    return intent;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the x and y as instance variables rather than local ones.